# How to deny application access for a user/group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate Docker image

```
lscr.io/linuxserver/webtop:ubuntu-mate
```

I can access the desktop via the browser. This works like a charm. However, I would like to restrict the `abc` (a `group` would also be ok) user. For example, how can I deny access of `mate-terminal`? Event better would be to only allow access to Firefox?

The problem is that I don't know much about the Linux environment, so I have no clue where to start. So, any help would be appreciated!!